# System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Try
    Dim url = "something"
    Dim request = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim httpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim dataStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
    If dataStream Is Nothing Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Dim reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Return reader.ReadToEnd()
Catch ex As WebException
    Return ""
End Try
```

---

Above code is working in LocalHost but in server it's not working and throwing an Exception.

> System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll but was not handled
>   in user code

Comment: The Exception is being thrown to the caller , check for the message from the exception

Comment: i am getting this message "Unable to connect to the remote server" from the Excepion.

Comment: i am assuming you are connected using a Proxy server . Check your Proxy Settings . If yes, Create a WebProxy object and assign it to the httpwebrequest

Comment: i don't have any idea about Proxy Server.Can u Help me.

Answer (score 0):

You're re-throwing the exception after the `Catch`.
Remove `Throw`.

```
 Try
    Dim url = "something"
    Dim request = WebRequest.Create(url)
    request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Dim httpWebResponse = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim dataStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
    If dataStream Is Nothing Then
        Return ""
    End If
    Dim reader = New StreamReader(dataStream)
    Return reader.ReadToEnd()
Catch ex As WebException
    Return ""
End Try
```

Comment: thanks but what is the reason of that kind of Exception.how can i stop the calling catch.

Comment: I guess it's connection issues with the url you're calling. Not a problem with your code.

Comment: Does not necessarily mean that it works on the other system as well. Could be firewall-settings or many other reasons. And the error message "Unable to connect to the remote server" says that it's a connection issue. Are you able to open the URL with a Webbrowser from the Server?

Comment: I am getting this error----------"This page can’t be displayed" when i  open the URL with a Webbrowser  from the Server.How can i solve it.

Comment: So it IS a connection issue on your server. I think your original question is answered. This is a coding forum...if you need network or server support you're in the wrong place here.